# My function outputs a "Seq" and not a String in F#?

Tags: f#

I am curious why when I run this, the function "parsenumber" gets outputted as a Seq and not just an int.

```
|> Seq.map (fun ((number,income,sex,house),data) -> 
    let parsenumber = number |> Seq.skip 9 |> Seq.take 5
    let numberofpets = data |> Seq.map (fun row -> (1.0 - float row.pets))
    ((parsenumber,income,sex,house),numberofpets)
```

This is the result:

```
(<seq>, "30050", "Male", "Yes")
(<seq>, "78000", "Female", "No")
```

How can I change this so it outputs the number and not `<seq>`.

With Seq.skip and Seq.take, I am trying to skip the first 9 integers of each observation in number and return the last 5.

RAW CSV DATA:

```
10000000001452,30050,Male,Yes
10000000001455,78000,Female,No
```

What I want as a result:

```
('01452','30050','Male','Yes')
('01455','78000','Female','No')
```

What I am actually getting:

```
(<seq>, "30050", "Male", "Yes")
(<seq>, "78000", "Female", "No")
```

I need to not have  as an output, and the actual number instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, "I am trying to skip the first 9 integers of each observation in number and return the last 5", did you mean "digits" rather than "integers"? I.e., is `number` a string originally? Then you should use `number.Substring(9, 5)` instead of `Seq.skip` and `Seq.take`. The `Seq.skip` and `Seq.take` functions are defined as returning sequences — that's what they're for. When you interpret a string as a sequence, it returns a sequence of characters. If you use the `.Substring` method, it returns a string.

BTW, if you want to use `.Substring`, you'll need to tell F# what type you expect `number` to be: calling methods of a parameter is one place where F#'s type inference can't figure out what type you have. (Because in theory, you could have defined your own type with a `.Substring` method and meant to call that type). To explicitly declare the type of the `number` parameter, you'd use a colon and the type name, so that `fun ((number,income,sex,house),data) ->` would become `fun ((number : string, income, sex, house), data) ->`. So your entire `Seq.map` expression would become:

```
|> Seq.map (fun ((number : string, income, sex, house), data) -> 
    let parsenumber = number.Substring(9, 5)
    let numberofpets = data |> Seq.map (fun row -> (1.0 - float row.pets))
    ((parsenumber, income, sex, house), numberofpets)
```

Also, `parsenumber` isn't a function, so that's not a good name for it. Possibly `parsednumber` would be better, though if I understood more about what you're trying to do then there's probably an even better suggestion.

Comment: for some reason, I am still getting `(<seq>, "30050", "Male", "Yes")
(<seq>, "78000", "Female", "No")` I need the <seq> to be the number I am skipping and then taking. Do you know why the actual number does not show up?

Comment: "... the number I am skipping and then taking". I have no idea what you mean by those words. Can you give me a specific example of the input you have, and the result you're trying to get? That might help me understand better.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to adjust the sample code to include the `.Substring` part. Fixed now.

Comment: Okay, then I was right that you want `.Substring`. Try the code in my answer again: the first time you tried it, I had forgotten to change your `Seq.skip |> Seq.take` expression to `.Substring`, so it's no surprise that you got the same result again. :-)

Comment: so is it not iterating through the sequence when i use Seq.take? is that the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172861/discussion-between-rmunn-and-ute).